# WCF-WebHttp Error Handling For Rest API BizTalk 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have a rest API with POST Method where I am posting and receiving success response as JSON format which works absolutely fine. During the failure I receive

> Error details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: 
>   (400) Bad Request The creation  failed because the name or email address of the is invalid

Which I see in Application log and send port gets suspended. I need to capture this in the BizTalk Orchestration where I need to send email if I get any error response.

As the Error Response is not in JSON format don't know how it can be handled. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable Routing for failed messages on the Send Port to stop the suspended messages.  You might have to update the filter in the send port that subscribes to `ErrorReport.FailureCode Exists` to exclude your API send port if you only want to handle these in the Orchestration.  If you don't have such a port, you might have to create one, and send the failed messages to a NULL adapter or similar.
2. Have your Orchestration have an scope with an exception block to catch System Exceptions, in there have  `Exception = SystemException.ToString();` in an Expression shape where Exception is a System.String Variable, and SystemException is the Exception Object Name you defined in the Catch block.
3. Have logic in your catch block that decides what sort of exception you got, I use a If shape with `Exception.Contains("XXXX")` where XXXX is text in the exception, or handle it however you want.