# Biztalk Custom WebHttpBinding to catch HTTP protocol exceptions / 40x codes

Tags: biztalk, wcf-binding

It is possible to create WCF-Custom Binding using WCF Web HTTP to handle HTTP protocol 400-500 codes in REST?

I'd like to have that binding and use it in Biztalk to return a Message object, not an Exception one that comes from send port.

I tried to create a custom binding element and use it in WCF-Custom binding but I realized that it operates on Soap Protocol, not on plain HTTP. It should be something like WCF-WebCustom binding but there is none.

As far as I understand I should implement my Web Binding based on [WCF Web HTTP Programming Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-object-model) . Am I right?

Comment: Not in the bindings no.  Either you have to catch them in the Orchestration, or you need to create a Endpoint Behavior that does it.    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158413/wcf-webhttp-error-handling-for-rest-api-biztalk-2016

Comment: I think this document will help you[WCF Web HTTP error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-error-handling)